# casperjs and phantomjs for downloading images via ajax results in cross-domain issue

Tags: ajax, download, casperjs

I am trying to automate downloading images from a site, and I am trying to use casperjs (1.1.4) and phantomjs (2.1.3) to do this

Doing this manually, I visit the site with a browser, log in, navigate to the desired images, select each, and then click a *Download* button. This then brings up the usual dialog for saving files.

In my code, I have figured out how to get as far as the download in my casperjs/phantomjs script, but I cannot successfully download an image using the `casper.download()` function. When I hover over the Download button, the URLs have this form:

```
https://www.frustrating.net/image/download?uri=https://frustrating.net/repo:/0495/4:1:8Q9MCSN3
```

But passing this URL (or even just the part after `uri=`) fails because casperjs says that it cannot handle cross-domain ajax requests.

In searching for answers, I find that many people have reported a problem more or less like this one, but there's no general solution.

Apparently, in recent versions of casperjs, there is a `sendAjax()` function, but it isn't clear to me how one gathers the information required by that function from the website that one is using, or even whether that function is what should be used in a situation like this.

How do I troubleshoot this? What information do I need to know in order to make casperjs download images from such a site? Since I'm learning javascript, I would ideally like to see some commented code that I could follow and modify as necessary. I can use Firefox's InspectElement feature to get more information, but it isn't clear to me what information I need.

Comment: Can you provide real website or url?

Comment: Sorry, I can't, as it requires a company account to log in and actually follow the link.  I realize this makes it more difficult, hence my question about what info I need to get from the server to figure out how to automate this.  I was hoping that the form of the url together with the error message would be diagnostic, but perhaps that's not the case.  Do you have a guess as to whether sendAjax() is even appropriate?